# Problem running TextTransform.exe when using T4Toolbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, t4, css, t4-toolbox

I'm attempting to run `TextTransform.exe` to generate code using a T4 template file. 
The template file is dependent on the `T4Toolbox` (specifically, it contains classes implementing the T4Toolbox.Template class).

As such, it includes the file `t4toolbox.tt`, which contains the following directives:

```
<#@ dte processor="T4Toolbox.DteProcessor" #>

<#@ TransformationContext processor="T4Toolbox.TransformationContextProcessor" #>
```

During execution, I get the following error for both the referenced processors:

```
C:\Program Files\T4 Toolbox\t4toolbox.tt(1,4) : error : A processor named 'T4Toolbox.DteProcessor' could not be found for the directive named 'dte'. The transfo
rmation will not be run.  The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to load directive processor T4Toolbox.DteProcessor.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CommandLine.CommandLineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String processorName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session, List`1 directivesT
oBeProcessed)
```

I'm running the exe with the following parameters:

```
TextTransform.exe
-I "C:\Program Files\T4 Toolbox" 
-P "[Framework3.5],[VS2008 PublicAssemblies]" 
-dp "XsdProcessor!T4Toolbox.XsdProcessor!T4Toolbox.dll" 
-r "T4Toolbox.dll" mytemplate.tt
```

I've tried to include addition directive processors with multiple -dp parameters, and with a comma separated list (I can see both the `DteProcessor` and `TransformationContextProcessor` are implemented in `T4Toolbox`, so presumably the syntax is similar to the specification of the `XsdProcessor`?)

Any ideas on how to get rid of these errors? The template generation runs perfectly inside visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the noted errors with some adjustments to the command line parameters.
TextTransform.exe seems to need multiple paths or directives specified individually. I also had the processing assembly incorrect (-r)

For example: 

`TextTransform.exe
-I "C:\Program Files\T4 Toolbox" 
-P "[path1]" 
-P "[path2]" 
-dp "T4Toolbox.DteProcessor!T4Toolbox.DteProcessor!T4Toolbox.dll" 
-dp "T4Toolbox.TransformationContextProcessor!T4Toolbox.TransformationContextProcessor!T4Toolbox.dll"

-r Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.dll" mytemplate.tt`

However, unfortunately, resolving these couple of issues led to a dead end.
Use of the T4Toolbox is not currently supported.

http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/discussions/52069

Instead, I'm looking at calling MSBuild.
The following has been a great reference: 
http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/#ConfiguringTransformationEnvironment